# How should "lookup" table look like in ER Diagram and in Models

Tags: sql, model-view-controller

I wanna know how does lookup table look like when drawn in ER Diagram and how does the relation between "main" table and lookup table look like when making their Models. Also, link to documentation and more info about them would be great.

Comment: You might *wanna* read, [ask] this question is lacking a little and basically is just asking for a link to documentation. Also it has little to do with C#

Comment: i removed c# tag, and I didn't want to write a lot because people start complaining that question should be as short as possible. And i don't want just documentation but to someone explain it as well. The biggest thing is that i searched everywhere and i couldn't find good examples of lookup tables in ERD that made sense to me. Also, how to make them in Models is also no where to be found